# Is my implementation of a pointer swap in Fortran correct?

Tags: pointers, fortran, swap

I am trying to optimise a code that relies on a memory bandwidth intensive propagation step between two arrays. One possible optimisation is using pointers to the actual arrays and swapping them instead of swapping the arrays themselves.
During the process I got a little unsure if I am doing it right.

Here is a stripped down version of what I did:

```
PROGRAM pointer_swap_minexample

    implicit none

    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: I4B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = KIND(1.0d0)
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: a, b
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pa, pb

    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: nmax = 1000
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: tmax = 1000
    INTEGER(I4B) :: n, t

    allocate(a(nmax), b(nmax))
    a(:) = 0.0_dp
    b(:) = 0.0_dp

    pa => a
    pb => b

    do t=1, tmax

        !=========================!
        ! heavy lifting goes here !
        !=========================!

        if(mod(t,2) .EQ. 1) then
            pa => b
            pb => a
        else
            pa => a
            pb => b
        end if

    end do

END PROGRAM pointer_swap_minexample
```

The actual code compiles and runs without errors. The output appears to be correct an the speedup compared to array swapping is there.
Is my implementation correct in general? Are there some caveats I should be aware of? Things I should do differently?

Comment: I do not see how this can run without error. Indeed, it crashes when I test it. You allocate memory for `pa` and `pb`, then throw it away by making `pa` and `pb` point to `a` and `b`, respectively. At that point you have no accessible, allocated arrays. You should instead allocate `a` and `b` directly.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I actually do. I just messed up my example. Corrected now.

Comment: In that case, I see nothing wrong with the code :)

Comment: Looks fine, but could be made slightly simpler by putting the "swap" before the "heavy lifting", making the test to be equality to zero (or better swapping the swap), and omitting the initialisation before the loop.